# Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to import an existing resources into the terraform state. I used the following:

```
terraform import azurerm_resource_group.main_rg /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/rg-cm-main
```

The resource group exist in the subscription with the name and ID.

but when I run the command, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object
```

do I need to do anything special in my script before I ran this command?

Comment: It sounds like the Azure provider is unable to find the resource group. Are you sure that's the correct path and you're using the correct subscription ID (assume you've just zero'd out the subscription ID rather than trying to use that literally)?

Comment: Yes, I have the right subscription ID. I have check the path several times I think it is right. (I assume by path you mean this: azurerm_resource_group.main_rg /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/rg-cm-main)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've seen the problem as well. For me it worked to set the correct subscription in my az cli tool. For some reason it was trying to find the resource via az cli in the wrong subscription.

```
az account list -o table
az account set -s
```

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Bingo. the -s should be --subscription <subscription name>

Comment: You can connect `azure-cli` to a specific subscription with `az login` and switch between subscriptions using the `az account set -s` command, or you connect `az login --allow-no-subscriptions`. It's uncommon but useful to run tenant level commands.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

```
export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=xxxxxxx-0000-4938-0000-cf87aexxxxxxx
terraform init -var-file="../env/${TFENV}/global.tfvars" -backend-config="../env/${TFENV}/backend.tfvars"
terraform import azurerm_resource_group.resource_group /subscriptions/xxxxxxx-0000-4938-0000-cf87aexxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxcore-dev-rg
```

Comment: Similar, you can set the `subscription_id` property of your `azurerm` `provider` block: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs#subscription_id